How can I display the colors represented in a sequence of RGB hex values?
I have a sequence of 6-digit hexadecimal values, with or without an 0x prefix, representing colors in RGB format, e.g. FF0000 for red and FFFF00 for yellow. The values are separated by spaces.
Example:
0x004586 0xff420e 0xffd320 0x579d1c 0x7e0021 0x83caff 0x314004 0xaecf00 0x4b1f6f 0xff950e 0xc5000b 0x0084d

I'm in a shell session in some terminal, and I want to see the represented colors, in one of three ways:

In the terminal itself
In an image file (of some common format) with contiguous areas of the different colors
In an X window - assuming my terminal has DISPLAY defined and there's an X server running which would allow access

any of the three is legitimate; the point is I want to do this without writing some complex bespoke program, but with something simple, preferably a one-liner. Can I do that?
Notes:

Assume a modern Linux system but try to refrain from overly exotic/esoteric tools.
Any of the three options for rendering the colors is fine; and if your solution supports more than one option, all the better.
Sometimes I have leading double-zeros, e.g. 0x00FF0000. You can choose to ignore this, or not to.


You should have at least made an effort to solve your own problem before posting a question here. HTML+Javascript in a web browser strikes me as one path of least resistance. Writing an image file is all very well but you also have to display it. Indexed 256 colour BMP would be my choice for that option (trample on the colour LUT).

Please show a proper example of your input data. Where is it? In a file? In a shell variable? How long could it be? 3-5 separate colours? Or 2 MP of a 1920x1080 image?

AFAIK max number of colors supported by terminal is 256. Personally I'm using this 16 colors pallet.

please define "see the represented colors". e.g. can you distinguish 00000 from 00001?

@MarkSetchell: Done.

@jhnc: I didn't say I needed to distinguish nearly-black from perfect-black. I just want to see them on screen.

Sometimes I have leading double-zeros if string are composed of 3 sequence of 1 to 4 digits, this is RGB. if string are composed of 4 sequences of 2 or 4 digis, this is RGBA, where A means  alpha, is a transparancy value!

This question is similar to: List of ANSI color escape sequences. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

U could have a look at tput setaf color table? How to determine color codes?

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub: Just leafed through it, and it seems quite complex. But I did see printf '\e[0;%s8;2;%s;%s;%sm▒▒▒ ' "$fb" "$r" "$g" "$b" suggested; if only I could figure out what "front/back" means, perhaps I could use that on the numbers after channel-decomposition.

@einpoklum Try (2nd) showColor function, from this comment

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

My idea would be to use ImageMagick to make a PNG that you can display with xdg-open, or feh, or eog or MS Paint.
Here's a script that makes a PNG with a red, green and blue block each 30x30 pixels all arranged in a row across the page. Save it as script.mgk:
-size 30x30
xc:#ff0000
xc:#00FF00
xc:#0000FF
+append
-write result.png

Now you can run it with:
magick-script script.mgk

and it will create this result.png:

I wrote it with both lower and upper-case hex so you can see that both work. It writes an output file called result.png - instead you could write a PNG on stdout by changing the last line to:
-write PNG:-

Then you could pipe that to feh or xdg-open:
magick-script script.mgk | feh


If your shell scripting is rusty, here's an outline of a possible approach:
# Generate a string of Hex values
PIXELS="FF0000 00FF00 0000FF"

{ printf "-size 30\n" ; echo $PIXELS | tr ' ' '\n' | sed 's/^/xc:#/g' ; printf "+append\n-write result.png"; }

That creates this script:
-size 30
xc:#FF0000
xc:#00FF00
xc:#0000FF
+append
-write result.png


Rather than make each pixel 30x30, you could omit the -size 30x30 and leave each pixel at the dafault 1x1 size, but then add a scaling up to make the result a nicely visible 800 px wide at the end - regardless of the number of pixels. Your script would look like this:
xc:#FF0000
xc:#00FF00
xc:#0000FF
+append
-scale 800x
-write result.png


I learned both about magic-script and about feh. Thanks :-)

I've posted @code-colf a bash script that run firefox with an inline javascript for browsing RGB colors

And you may find on my own site: a bash HSV-RGB library, with a color browser (and a demo;).

Just [tag:bash]: this function: showColor() {  printf '\n\e[A\e[48;2;%d;%d;%dm    \n\r    \e[0m\n' 0x${1:1:2} 0x${1:3:2} 0x${1:5:2};} you could use in any terminal: showColor "#00FF00" of better, with a loop for processing all arguments: showColor() { for a;do printf '\n\e[A\e[48;2;%d;%d;%dm    \n\r    \e[0m\n' 0x${a:1:2} 0x${a:3:2} 0x${a:5:2};done;}, then showColor "#00FF00" "#FF0000" "#0000FF" "#368AEF"

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub Don't be shy! Make an answer where it can be well formatted, easily seen and gain points - your suggestion is good.

The question isn't! There is a lot of answer. Most IDE (emacs, vim)  will shown color directly in interface. you could use tools from any graphic editor, from paint to gimp... Finally this question has already an answer...

This solution is by @FHauri in a comment, with some tweaking. Use this bash function:
function showColors() { 
   for rgbval; do
       printf '\n\e[A%06x  \e[48;2;%d;%d;%dm   \e[0m\n' \
           0x${rgbval:2:6} \
           0x${rgbval:2:2} \
           0x${rgbval:4:2} \
           0x${rgbval:6:2};
   done;
}

which writes some space characters in the appropriate color, plus preceding and succceding control stuff.
then invoke:
showColors 0x004586 0xff420e 0xffd320 0x579d1c 0x7e0021 0x83caff 0x314004 0xaecf00 0x4b1f6f 0xff950e 0xc5000b 0x0084d

you'll get this:

the function can be adapted to strip initial 0x prefixes, ignore leading zeros etc.
